# Let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $x = a$. Show that $f$ must be bounded in an open interval centred at $x = a$.

Tags: real-analysis

Let $f :\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be continuous at $x = a$. Show that $f$ must be bounded in an open interval centered at $x = a$.

I am completely lost on how I should approach this.

Comment: What have you done?

Comment: @Jack, hello. I should've clarified. I am completely lost on how I should approach this.

Comment: what does it mean for $f$ to be continuous at x=a?

Comment: Have you went to the epsilon-delta definition and tried approaching it through an inequality?

Comment: When in  doubt write down the definition of every relevant term.  In this case continuous is the big one.  Now fit what you need to prove from the definition.

Answer (score 2):

Answering simpler questions would be a way to **get started** when you feel totally lost:

- (1)What does $f$ being continuous at $x=a$ mean? Can you write down the *definition*?
- (2)What does "an open interval centered at $x=a$" mean? Can you write it down mathematically?
- (3)What does $f$ being bounded in an open interval mean?
- (4)Can you see how (1) and (2) might relate to (3)?

Comment: (1) $f(a)$ exists, the limit as $x \to a$ exists. (2) $(a-\delta , a+\delta)$?, (3) It means that $f$ has a upper (sup) and lower (inf) bound on the interval. Maybe $a - \delta$ is GLB and $a + \delta$ is LUB? (4) Not yet but I'm trying hard to...

Comment: (1) is incorrect, you need more. Also, do you know the $\epsilon$-$\delta$ definition of continuity?

Comment: Yes, for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| < \epsilon$.

Comment: What can this tell you about $f$ on the interval $(a-\delta,a+\delta)$? Can you find a lower bound and an upper bound for $f$ on this interval?

Comment: Wouldn't the lower bound be $f(a-\delta)$ and upper bound $f(a+\delta)$?

Comment: What can the inequality about $f$ tell you?

Comment: That $|f(a-\delta) - f(a)|<\epsilon$. Same for the upper bound. So $f(a-\delta)\le f(a)\le f(a+\delta)$?

Comment: That is not correct. One more hint: $|x-a|<\delta$ iff $x\in(a-\delta,a+\delta)$. Similarly you have $f(x)\in(f(a)-\epsilon,f(a)+\epsilon)$ iff...

Comment: ..Iff $|f(x)-f(a)|<\epsilon$... So $f(x)$ must be bounded by $f(a)$?

Comment: Find a bound now?

Comment: Wait, bounded by $f(a)-\epsilon$ and $f(a)+\epsilon$...?

Comment: You get the idea now.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Continuity at $a$ reads as: for every $\epsilon > 0$ there is a $\delta$ such that if $|x - a| < \delta$ then $|f(x) - f(a)| \le \epsilon$.

Consider the open interval $(a - \delta, a + \delta)$ and remember that $|a| - |b| \le |a - b|$.

Comment: Thank you. For clarification, by triangle inequality isn't $|a-b| \leq |a| - |b|$?

Comment: @ozarka: what if $b=1$ and $a=0$?